# How to know if my comment is viewed by recipient

Tags: feature-request, comments

I would like to know if there is any possibility to find out whether my comment is viewed by the recipient or not?

**For example :**

I ask a question, and somebody adds a comment to it.

I reply with @Recipient and some comments.

After 2 hours if I check `Recipient seen time` it says "30 minutes ago".

Is there a system like this, where I can see whether the recipient has seen my comment or not? Should we create one?

Comment: Down Voters please give your comments.

Comment: See the [meta-faq#vote-differences]; votes on Meta are different from the regular Stack Exchange websites. You tagged this as a feature request, perhaps the downvoters are disagreeing this should be implemented?

Comment: I disagree with the Close Vote. As a feature-request this is valid. As a support question, it is objectively answerable.

Comment: @S.L.Barth yeah sure thanks for support.Lots of Messengers like facebook are having this feature very useful.

Comment: If they have responded you know they have seen it :)

Comment: Next you'll want a feature to verify that the person understood the comment. And then maybe if they did what you asked them to do. This is not a chat system, it is a Q&A site.

Comment: Just as a clarification, sunleo: @S.L.Barth was not saying that he necessarily *agreed* with your feature request; merely that it was valid *as* a feature request. Maybe he does agree or not, but just wanted to make sure you didn't assume something that wasn't meant. ;)

Comment: Frankly, I *hate* read receipts - they're intrusive, and only serve as a way to muscle people into responding to you. If they read your comment and want to respond, then they will.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to know whether your comment has been viewed or not.

A notification will have been delivered to their inbox, but that's all you can guarantee.